# Javascript make calculations and filter list

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have below array -

```
const data=[
{
  month:"nov",
  veryLate:3,
  Late:5,
  onTime:2
},
{
  month:"dec",
  veryLate:1,
  Late:3,
  onTime:16
},
{
  month:"jan",
  veryLate:28,
  Late:1,
  onTime:1
},
}
```

I want to filter and make calculations on this array such that percentage can be obtained.

Eg. veryLate + Late+ onTime = (3+5+2) = 10

So percentage wise it is -

```
const data= [
{
  month:"nov",
  veryLate:30,
  Late:50,
  onTime:20
},
{
  month:"dec",
  veryLate:5,
  Late:15,
  onTime:80
},
,
{
  month:"jan",
  veryLate:98.33,
  Late:3.33,
  onTime:3.33
},]
```

To calculate this I had performed below , but getting syntax error over brackets -

```
var filteredData=data.map(x=>{
  x.month,
  x.veryLate/(x.veryLate+x.Late+x.onTime)*100,
  x.Late/(x.veryLate+x.Late+x.onTime)*100,
  x.onTime/(x.veryLate+x.Late+x.onTime)*100,
});
```

How can I obtained calculated results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x.veryLate wont work in x it should be veryLate itself same for the others

```js
const data=[
{
  month:"nov",
  veryLate:3,
  Late:5,
  onTime:2
},
{
  month:"dec",
  veryLate:1,
  Late:3,
  onTime:16
},
{
  month:"jan",
  veryLate:28,
  Late:1,
  onTime:1
},
]

var filteredData= data.map(x => (
   {
    ...x, 
    veryLate:  x.veryLate/(x.veryLate+x.Late+x.onTime)*100,         
    Late: x.Late/(x.veryLate+x.Late+x.onTime)*100, 
    onTime: x.onTime/(x.veryLate+x.Late+x.onTime)*100
  })
)

console.log(filteredData)
```

You also must wrap the returning object literal into parentheses. Currently the curly braces is being denoted as the function body.

Answer (score 1):

The `map()` method needs to return a value.

Try this

```
var filteredData=data.map(x => {
   // get the original values to avoid repeating x. 
   const {month, veryLate, Late, onTime} = x;
   
   // do your calculations
   const newVeryLate = veryLate / ( veryLate + Late + onTime) * 100;
   const newLate = Late / (veryLate + Late + onTime) * 100;
   const newOnTime = onTime / (veryLate + Late + onTime) * 100;
   
   // return the new object
   return {month, veryLate: newVeryLate, Late: newLate, onTime: newOnTime}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var filteredData=data.reduce((a, v)=>{
  let obj = {};
  let sum = v.veryLate+v.Late+v.onTime;
  obj.month = v.month;
  obj.veryLate = v.veryLate/sum*100;
  obj.Late = v.Late/sum*100;
  obj.onTime = v.onTime/sum*100;
  a.push(obj)
  return a;
}, []);
```

Throwing error because:

1. The data array has no closing bracket
2. map method is not returning anything. if you want to return an object from it use return keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the callback passed to [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) needs to return something for every iteration and in your current implementation you aren't returning anything.

You can use `map` as shown below:

```js
const data = [
  { month: "nov", veryLate: 3, Late: 5, onTime: 2 },
  { month: "dec", veryLate: 1, Late: 3, onTime: 16 },
  { month: "jan", veryLate: 28, Late: 1, onTime: 1 },
];

const filteredData = data.map(({ month, veryLate, Late, onTime }) => {
  const total = veryLate + Late + onTime;
  return {
    month,
    veryLate: (veryLate / total) * 100,
    Late: (Late / total) * 100,
    onTime: (onTime / total) * 100,
  };
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

If you're finding `map` confusing, you can also do it with a regular `for` loop, as shown below:

```js
const data = [
  { month: "nov", veryLate: 3, Late: 5, onTime: 2 },
  { month: "dec", veryLate: 1, Late: 3, onTime: 16 },
  { month: "jan", veryLate: 28, Late: 1, onTime: 1 },
];

const filteredData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const { month, veryLate, Late, onTime } = data[i];
  const total = veryLate + Late + onTime;
  result.push({
    month,
    veryLate: (veryLate / total) * 100,
    Late: (Late / total) * 100,
    onTime: (onTime / total) * 100,
  });
}

console.log(filteredData);
```

Additional Documentation:

- [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)